# aframe vr-mode projection matrices

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality

Just want to know: what exactly are the left and right camera projection matrices a-frame uses by default when entering VR mode?

Can someone give me two 4x4 matrices with numbers or do they depend on browser and device?

Answer (score 0):

The matrix are provided by the WebVR API (WebXR in the future) and are hardware dependent as you mentioned. More info in the [VRFrameData docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VRFrameData)